YA fantasy book that features a crow, a magical realm, and England(?)
I've been thinking about this book a lot and for the life of me I cannot remember it. I will list as much as I can remember. My googling powers apparently suck and I can't find anything besides books with crow in the title.

Most likely published between 2004 - 2015. I know that's a wide range. I'd guess closer to 2004-2010.
Main character (MC) is visiting grandparents or aunt/uncle in the countryside for summer. Has a younger sibling. I cannot remember if they were a boy or girl. Younger sibling is a boy. I'm pretty confident in that.
Modernish times. 1950s onward. possibly early 2000s and MC is annoyed at the oldness of where they are staying. No video games/computer. Not 100% on this though.
Young Adult.
Crows or ravens show up and start doing things to draw the MC's attention. Leaves things in the garden. Eventually leaves something that freaks the MC out enough they don't want to go outside and the family members make fun of them. Could have been a creepy symbol or a bone or something.
I think "our world" is set in England.
MC is pre-teen to teenaged.
Crows/ravens lure younger sibling outside to get MC to come after them.
MC gets spirited away to a magical realm. Lots of animal based creatures. I think the crow/raven could talk.
MC has to go on a long journey across this land to help the crow defeat the big bad.
Had a creepy unsettling feeling to it.
MC was the only one who could beat the big bad for some reason.
If big bad wasn't defeated everything was going to die.
Lots of ties to death?

That's it. I've literally only ever found one other person who claims to remember this book but they can't remember the name either. It would have been paperback. Most likely purchased at Borders or Barnes and Nobel. I live in the US.
Please help! I feel like I've just made this book up.

Sounds to have some elements in common with The Dark Is Rising, but not all of it matches.  Also, that sequence was published between 1965 and 1977.

Yea, that one has come up a lot and it wasn't it. Similar plot points on occasion.

The Dark is Rising - agreed.

@PatWagnerDenver that one comes up all the time. I has a lot of similar elements but it isn't it. I'm fairly certain it was a stand alone book and that the MC doesn't team up with anyone besides the odd creatures of this magical realm. The crow was either a messenger for or was the MCs mentor/teacher.
